# DynamoDB on-demand mode suddenly stops working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that is incrementally populated with a lambda function every hour. The write capacity metric is full of predictable spikes and throttling was normally avoided by relying on the burst capacity.

The first three loads after turning on-demand mode on kept working. Thereafter it stopped loading new entries into the table and began to time-out (from ~10 seconds to the current limit of 4 minutes). The lambda function was not modified at all.

Does anyone know why might this be happening?

[image: Write capacity metric]

**EDIT**: I just see timeouts in the logs.

- Logs before failure

[image]

- Logs after failure

[image]

- Errors and availability (%)

[image]

Comment: Does your lambda have logs in Cloudwatch? Are you seeing an error, or just a timeout?

Comment: Just timeouts apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Lambda to perform incremental writes, this issue is more than likely on Lambda side. That is where I would start looking for this. Do you have CW logs to look through? If you cannot find it, open a case with AWS support.

Comment: It seems like a suspicious coincidence. I edited the answer to show the actual logs and opened a case, thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: The issue was indeed on Lambda side. Just an unlikely coincidence on timings.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this was recently fixed, there is a known bug in Lambda where you can get a series of timeouts. We encountered it on a project I worked on: a lambda would just start up and sit there doing nothing, quite like yours.

So like Kirk, I'd guess the problem is with the Lambda, not DynamoDB.

At the time there was no fix. As a workaround, we had another Lambda checking the one that suffered from failures and rerunning those. Not sure if there are other solutions. Maybe deleting everything and setting it back up again (with your fingers crossed :))? Should be easy enough if everything is in Cloudformation.